# Should one use Assert in a method without TestMethod attribute?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I am taking over a legacy code in C# and *unit* testing of this code just doesn't work.

Let me explain by the following code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest() {
    ...
    // Parallel call of this method via Threading
    TestUtil(args);
    ...
}

private void TestUtil(...) {
    ...
    Assert.IsTrue(Condition1);
    Assert.IsTrue(Condition2);
}
```

When I run *SampleTest* in Visual Studio, instead of marking the test as failed (because some condition fails), VS throws an exception in QTAgent.exe.

Do you know why QTAgent.exe crashes in this case instead of failing the test?

Comment: If the function you call is part of the Unit Test, then you shouldn't have to use `TestMethod` attribute. Those are generally used to be triggered by test automation to run all the unit tests, you don't want that TestUtil to be run separately, so no, don't use the `[TestMethod]` attribute on it. It's fine to continue using Assert within the scope of a Test method calling on a private function.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's totally fine to put asserts into private methods in your test class.
Private methods can basically be viewed as code that logically belongs in the main method, but has been broken out for readability or code reuse.
I commonly put asserts into private methods if the asserts are identical between multiple tests

Comment: I'm convinced that's it's fine to put asserts in private methods. Perhaps it's because of the threading that caused QTAgent.exe to crash instead of failing the test? Do you know what happened and/or why?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. It has nothing to do with Assert or TestMethod or threading. The exception was thrown because of a missing library.

Hence, if possible, I'd like to delete this question.